# Turn signal lights for bikes

Tags: safety, lighting, signals, led-lights

I am interested in buying turn signal lights for bicycles. I read something about here and in other websites, but I did not find answers for the following questions:

- For the point of view of a driver, is it better to use a hand signal or if a turn signal light?
- Is it safer? How much (are there any statistics)?
- What are your personal opinion? I think a bit difficult to balance while making signals with my arm, so I thought about using these lights. Since cars are not familiar with bike in streets (where I live at least), I thought about using a super strong turn signal lights.
- Do you recommend any particular type?

Comment: One issue is separation between the left and right signal lights. If the light isn't clearly on one side or the other observers will struggle to tell which way, if any, the rider is turning. It might just be an orange blinky light used as a headlight or taillight.

Comment: There was recently a kickstarter for turn signal gloves.  A yellow LED or 3 in a wristband would have a similar effect - then you get both the arm signal and the flashing yellow indicator.  Combined with red rear lights on bike and helmet/body this would give the separation discussed below.

Comment: I'm just thinking, might there be a legal view here? I'm just thinking if the bike regs where you are stipulate that you must particularly use hand signals? I know, such a law would be nonsense, but that doesn't seem to stop them!

Comment: somewhere I've seen indicator lights that go in the end of flat bars (so they're visible from the front, rather than just the back as the drop bar ones are). I might have been a kickstarter, but if someone knows can they post a link? I want some :)

Comment: I think this is a daft idea.  All road users have a limited amount of cognitive ability, and distracting them with unexpected signals then expecting them to comprehend and implement that quickly just takes away from everything else they have to do.   I point out the similarities with animated brake lights or indicator lights on cars, where other road users get distracted.

Comment: There was kickstarter last summer for a helmet that has headlight, turn signals and taillight/stop light. the turn signals are operated by a handlebar control and he stop light operates by a speedometer.

Comment: Many good arguments against, but if you do want to install indicators, then I suggest they should resemble standard motorbike signals as much as possible. On kickstarter you find many new ideas (I've seen a single display with a rotating red or green arrow, lights on helmet and others) that look great in a promotional video but in real traffic most people wouldn't recognise them as turn signals, in particular as some cyclists now carry multiple blinking and flashing lights.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd recommend learning to do arm signals.

Arm signals don't run out of batteries, and are plenty visible in most cases. They're certainly bigger than the turn signal lights you could put on a bicycle (which as Moz points out in a comment, makes distinguishing the 2 turn signals a possible issue), and the distance you need to see a bike turning is a lot smaller than that which you need to see a car turning.You also have to worry about running wires from the back to front if you only have one power source (and the indicator switch isn't wireless) and worry about bags or other things obscuring the lights. Your handlebar area also becomes a bit more cluttered for a turn signal anyway, esp if you have trigger shifters. And you have to deal with the potential of the lights getting stolen.

At night, the primary value would be moreso the extra light rather than the fact that it was a turn signal light, and you can get that just by putting on a bigger head and tail light.

You'll get used to balancing while doing them after a few weeks of riding, typically. And in any case, you need to know how to do them when your batteries run out.

IMO, the primary use of turn signals on a bike is less-so that you know which way a turn is happening, but moreso that the drivers know the cyclist is going to do something and be prepared for it (a sentiment echoed by one of the comments).

Comment: Plus there's the simple fact that no one expects turn signals on a bike and therefore won't readily recognize them for what they are. I'm old enough to remember when turn signals on motorcycles were fairly new things, and that was the problem with them then. Drivers simply didn't recognize them as turn signals. It took years of having them mandatory on all motorcycles before you could count on drivers recognizing them.

Comment: @CareyGregory motorists often struggle with hand or arm signals too, because few cyclists use them. That's a whole 'nother discussion though.

Comment: @Mσᶎ people tend to understand well enough if you point to where you're going though.

Comment: @nhinkle People tend to see the arm gesture well after they see the cyclist, if they see the gesture. It's less about understanding-after-they-see and more about how long it takes to get to that point.

Comment: In the US, though the laws vary, most state safety agencies recommend using the right arm extended to signal a right turn.  This is unambiguous and easy to understand.

Comment: In the US I see a lot of motorcycle riders use the hand signals as well in high visibility areas (busy highways) so motorist are understanding when they see it.  My driving portion of my drivers education had us demonstrate them, but that was only 1 time and 15 minutes at that.  Make it obvious it is a hand signal by keeping it stiff and straight, not flapping around or "waving to your neighbor".  As for doing it from a car (like my classic car with a unresolved issue), I think I'm the only person that uses them.

Comment: Try a Nite-ize slap it if you want to be more visible while signaling.  It's both reflective and lighted, so if you are riding at night, your hand signals should be a bit more visible.

http://www.niteize.com/product/SlapLit.asp

Comment: I use a plain reflective velcro strap (like http://hooptedoodle.typepad.com/hooptedoodle/images/2008/05/14/leg_bands.jpg) on my pant legs normally - Based on prior experience at least, the slap bracelet type often is prone to falling off on legs (especially in winter). I'm sure its a bit better on hands, but I'd be a bit worried about losing it (and I don't know how much advantage it has over a non LED one given when signaling you essentially get optimal reflection angle.

Comment: Also, @Mσᶎ - you can't signal the same way on a car as on a bike - you have to use up/down right angle, and arm fully out since you can't reach over to the other side on (most) cars. Those are also a little more complicated to parse than arm in direction though (which anyone can understnad).

Comment: The only major issue with arm signals is trying to keep signaling long enough.  In Ohio, a quick wave is all that's "required" to meet the letter of the law (and even that is considered second priority to safe operation of the bike/controls).  I often find it challenging to fit even that quick wave in when in rough/challenging conditions.  I doubt motorists even see it half the time.  You have to catch them when they're not busy checking the speedo, tuning the radio, yelling at the kids.  Something longer running *would* be an advantage.

Answer (score 4):

Learn to look back while riding straight. That is much more important than making any signal. Also the movement of the head is usually a good indication to the driver behind of what your intentions are.

Comment: And also communicate by taking the right position on the road, move to the left side of the road before the actual turn left. It's a clear indication of what your planning to do, and you're out of the way of the car behind you more quickly when you make the turn.

Answer (score 3):

I think electric turn signals on bicycle are a silly idea. As a motorcycle rider, I know that cars ignore turn signals.  Motorbikes and bicycles are invisible to cars.

On my bicycle, I do my hand signals (especially the left turns in the USA where I'm crossing against traffic) in conjunction with looking back and making eye-contact with whatever homicidal cager is threatening to run me down. I also signal lane shifts the same way. Hand signals are a visible claiming of space and the head turn / eye-contact is a critical part of this.

(On my motorbike, I tend do lane changes with hand signals. Pointing to the space that I'll occupy along with a death glare at the car behind me is much more effective than a little blinker).

Answer (score 3):

Suggested compromise: Hand signals, but wear reflective material on your arms to make those signals more visible.